# Two instruments vertically aligned

Tags: alignment, musixtex

I tried to make some music excerpts with two instruments using musixtex. I've got some alignment problems between the two instruments.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
  \begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    \instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
    \setstaffs1{2} % with two staffs
    \setclef{1}{60} % clef de fa (6) en 1, clef de sol (0) en 2
    \startextract % starting real score
      \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{IV} \hl M|\zhu{f h}\hu j\en
      \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{V} \hl N|\zhu{d g}\hu i\en
      \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{I} \hu J|\zhu{e g}\hu j\en
      \setdoublebar
    \endextract
   \end{music}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get
[image]

As we can see, the bass is not aligned with the tremble. How can I get a better alignment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the  blank spaces before `\hl` and `\hu`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \parindent10mm
        \instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
        \setstaffs1{2} % with two staffs
        \setclef{1}{60} % clef de fa (6) en 1, clef de sol (0) en 2
        \startextract % starting real score
        \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{IV}\hl M|\zhu{f h}\hu j\enotes
        \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{V}\hl N|\zhu{d g}\hu i\enotes
        \NOtes \zcharnote{-6}{I}\hu J|\zhu{e g}\hu j\enotes
        \setdoublebar
        \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I not understand the difference between the question and your answer, but I like it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Look at the vertical alignment of the upper and lower last notes.

Comment: Ah now I have understood ☹️